# Customizing Devise method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Devise in my web application and was wondering how to use a different button than the default one to submit information. I am attempting to embed it in a twitter boot strap modal, and use a button in the footer of the modal to submit the info, rather than the standard signup button. Here's what I have for code right now:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <h4>...</h4>
  <p>...</p></b>
  <p>...</p>
  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
      <div>
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email %>
      </div>
      <div>
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
      </div>
      <div>
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
      </div>
      <div>
        <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

In essence, I am trying to make the button in this line

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</a>
```

do what the button in this line does:

```
<div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
```

Anybody out there have any experience with this?

Comment: So you want to keep the form submit button from devise and also add another button in modal-footer to do the same thing?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to delete the ugly looking form submit button from devise and replace it with a button in the modal-footer that does the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just extend the form... say to cover the modal body and the footer too, and replace the link

do something like

```
<%= form_for ..... %>
   <div class="modal-body">
     your form fields should go here somewhere
     .....
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
     <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
     <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Because this seems a little too obvious, I'm not really sure I understood your question very well. If that's the case, let me know

Comment: I think he needs <% f.submit "Sign Up", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>

Comment: this solved it. I was worried that having the footer in the block would cause problems, but it seems to work perfectly. thanks!

Comment: Glad it's fixed. You should consider marking the answer as resolved

Answer (score 0):

A button is different than a link and think that you will have the issues. I have done very similar things recently and instead of using submit.

`<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit"value="Submit" >`

This is what I use in my rails applications inbetween the form tags. It's not as pretty as using rails, but it works.